# WP query arrays in array

Tags: wordpress

Hello I have array field "addresses" where are another array fields. I need in this fields filter by address. How I can write meta_query? Like this:

```
array(
    'key'       => 'addresses',
    'value'     => $location,
    'compare'   => 'LIKE',
  )
```

For echoing address I use:

`$address = get_field('addresses');
echo $address[0]["adresa"]["address"];`

Thanks for all answers.